# Euclidean geometry: Circle incribed in a circle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

Circle $c_2$ - with center $N$ - is inside circle $c_1$ and is tangent to circle $c_1$ - with center $M$ -  in $P$. The line $l$ intersects $c_1$ at points $A$ and $D$ and $c_2$ at points $B$ and $C$.

How do I proof that $\angle  APB = \angle  CPD$ and that $\angle  MPD = 90^{\circ} - \angle PAD$?

[image]

Comment: make a tangent line through P,check what happen.

Comment: A hint: for you first question use [homothety](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Homothety) with respect to $P$.

Answer (score 1):

For the second part, extend $PM$ to be a diameter of $c_1$, cutting it at $Q$.

Then $\angle QDP$ is a right angle so $\angle PQD$ is $90$ degrees minus $\angle QPD$ (i.e. minus $\angle MPD$).

But $\angle PAD$ equals $\angle PQD$ as angles subtended by the same arc.